# printf an integer of unknown precise type

Tags: c

I have put in my code a

```
typedef int myinteger ;
```

I want however all my code to continue to be valid if I change the typedef to another integer type.

Now I want to printf a variable of type `myinteger`. Is it a way to do it properly? I have just found the following "hack":

```
printf("%lld", myvariable) ;
```

hoping that any integer type will fit in a `long long` and that the compiler will do the proper conversion. It seems to works with gcc (although I have a warning). `printf` is a problem but they can be other problems too (like finding the maximum "myinteger").

More generally is it possible/desirable to try what I try to achieve, writing code assuming only that `myinteger` refers to some integer type?

Comment: I'd take a leaf out of the C99 book, they defined a couple of macro's for formats like `uint64_t` (for which the format is the `PRIu64` macro). Just add a `#define MYINT_F "%d"` to go with your `typedef`, and change the format string in accordance to the type

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend:

```
typedef int my_type_t;
#define FMT_MY_TYPE "%d"
```

Then:

```
my_type_t my_var = 0;
printf("Here is my_var: " FMT_MY_TYPE "\n", my_var);
```

This even works with structs. Here is a generalization:

```
typedef struct { int a; int b; } my_struct_t;
#define FMT_MY_STRUCT "{a: %d, b: %d}"
#define FMT_MY_STRUCT_ARG(x) (x).a, (x).b
```

Then:

```
my_struct_t my_var = {0, 1};
printf("Here is my_var: " FMT_MY_STRUCT "\n", FMT_MY_STRUCT_ARG(my_var));
```

Answer (score 5):

There's no universal format specifier that can be used in `printf()` to print *any* integer type. One way is to cast to C99's `intmax_t` or `uintmax_t` and print it:

```
#include <stdint.h>

printf("%jd\n", (intmax_t)myvariable);
printf("%ju\n", (uintmax_t)myvariable);
```

This will work for all integer types as `intmax_t`/`uintmax_t` is the type maximum width integer.

In general, arbitrarily changing the `typedef` suggests there's a fundamental flaw in the design.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to cast to `long long` in the call to `printf()` as it's the longest integer type:

```
printf("%lld", (long long)myvariable);
```

Comment: "it's the longest integer type"?   Since C99, `intmax_t` and `uintmax_t` are the "Greatest-width integer types" C11dr 7.20.1.5

Answer (score 1):

> It seems to works with gcc (although I have a warning).

You **need** to add a cast.

```
printf("%lld", (long long) myvariable);
```

> More generally is it possible/desirable to try what I try to achieve, writing code assuming only that "myinteger" refer to some integer type?

The "generic" `printf` call is a bad design smell. Moreover, what if `myvariable` is of type `unsigned long long` and its value is greater than `LLONG_MAX`?

Comment: Of course it won't work for the unsigned... but I fear that what you say is correct generic printf is bad. Is there any better way to do what I want?

Comment: @Olivier one solution is just to avoid the `typedef`. Personally I dislike `typedef` and found that most of the time it's a way to obfuscate code.

Comment: @Olivier : The "*better way*" is called C++ -  `std::cout << myvariable` - which is not the answer you are perhaps looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Consider branching depending on whether the value is negative, and casting to the `intmax_t` and `uintmax_t` types; there's no guarantee that `long long int` or `unsigned long long int` be the largest integer types, yet these `max` types are guaranteed to be the largest.

For example:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
/* ... */
if (my_variable < 0) printf("%jd", (intmax_t)  my_variable);
else                 printf("%ju", (uintmax_t) my_variable);
```

Answer (score 0):

If all code needs to do is print the integer, and using C99 or C11, use `_Generic` to select the matching print specifier.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define IntegerFormat3(X) _Generic((X), \
  size_t: "%zu", \
  ptrdiff_t: "%td", \
  default: 0 \
 )

#define IntegerFormat2(X) _Generic((X), \
  intmax_t: "%jd", \
  uintmax_t: "%ju", \
  default: IntegerFormat3(X) \
 )

#define IntegerFormat(X) _Generic(X, \
  _Bool: "%d", \
  char: "%c", \
  signed char: "%hhd", \
  unsigned char: "%hhu", \
  short: "%hd", \
  unsigned short: "%hu", \
  int: "%d", \
  unsigned: "%u", \
  long: "%ld", \
  unsigned long: "%lu", \
  long long: "%lld", \
  unsigned long long: "%llu", \
  default: IntegerFormat2(X) \
  )

int main(void) {
  int i = 12;
  unsigned long long u = 34;
  size_t sz = 56;
  printf(IntegerFormat(i), i);
  printf(IntegerFormat(u), u);
  printf(IntegerFormat(sz), sz);
  return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately `printf(IntegerFormat(i) "\n", i);` does not work.

Another C approach to formatted printing without *any* coded type dependent specifiers [Formatted print without the need to specify type matching specifiers using _Generic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/115143/formatted-print-without-the-need-to-specify-type-matching-specifiers-using-gene).

Still, casting to the widest matching sign-ness type is simple as answered by others.